# Mootools Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using mootools to create a scrollbar for content example code can be seen here

http://jsfiddle.net/scottmwilliams1/jSZDJ/1/

At the moment the scrollbar appears whatever the length of the content. I need to change the code so that the scrollbar disappears if the content is short and doesn't require scrolling. Mootool version needs to remain the same. Can anyone help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? **http://jsfiddle.net/CqrFp/**

I updated your fiddle implementing that feature.
Try to remove some text and see how the scrollbar disappears.

Comment: Thanks, That's almost perfect the only issue is I have more then one scrollbar on the page. So I guess hiding and showing the scrollbar needs to be work out for each item. At the moment if one scrollbar is shown it's shown for all of them.

Comment: Just so you can see what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/scottmwilliams1/ch6Sj/1/

Comment: So close only issue seems to be if you have more content in the second scrollbar the first still shows the scroll bars container

http://jsfiddle.net/scottmwilliams1/AHFcU/1/